# Initialization of class with deleted default constructor in different c++11 standard versions

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, value-initialization, deleted-functions

*In the duplicate there is no answer to the points **1** and **4** of my question at least. And they are the most important. I can delete the other points but I ask not to close the whole question.*

**1.** In code below obj1 is created normally. But if I try to uncomment obj2's and obj3's creations the compilation (-std=c++11, g++ 4.9.2) will fail. Why is it so? I thought that initialization should be performed identically regardless of whether an objct's memory was allocated on stack or on heap.

---

```
struct C
{
    int c;

    C() = delete;
};

int main()
{   
    C obj1 { };

    C *obj2 = (C *) malloc(sizeof(C));
    //new ((void *) obj2) C{ };

    //C* obj3 = new C{ };

    return 0;
}
```

**2.** I tried to figure out which of the two kinds of behaviour (obj1-case or obj2,obj3-cases) is correct according to standard.
In standard it's said (#3242 and #3337, 8.5.4):

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as
>   follows:
>
> — If the initializer list has no elements and T is a class
>   type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.

Okay. So I go to value-initialization definition (#3242 and #3337, 8.5.0):

> if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a
>   user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if
>   T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that
>   constructor is called.

According to (#3242, 12.1)

> A default constructor is trivial if it is neither user-provided nor deleted and if: . . .

and so deleted default constructor is **non-trivial** and, thus, the code *C obj1 { };* should fail to compile.

But according to (#3337, 12.1)

> A default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if: . . .

and so deleted default constructor is **trivial** the code *C obj1 { };* should succeed to compile.

Where is the truth?

**3.** But there is more. In the next version of standard it's said (#**3367**, 8.5.4):

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as
>   follows:
>
> — If T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed
>
> — Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and T is a class
>   type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.

As I understand ***C*** is an aggregate. But here I have a problem: I failed to find info how an aggregate with a deleted defult constructor is created. There is no such info in *8.5.1 Aggregates*. But according to this

> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as specified
>   in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list are taken as
>   initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript
>   or member order. Each member is copy-initialized from the
>   corresponding initializer-clause . . .  (#3367, 8.5.1)

I can suppose that constructors [compiler-generated in aggregates' case] are just ignored during aggregate-initialization. So I can suppose that the deleted default constructor is also simply ignored and so *C obj { };* should be compiled successfully though for me it's weird to create an object with **deleted** default constructor. Still if I understand right, according to this version of standard obj1-case is okay and it's wrong that obj2,obj3-cases fail to compile. Am I right?

**4.** And the logical question is, anyway, which standard version #3242/#3337 or #3367 should I rely on? Version #3367 was made in 2012, so later than 2011, and I don't know if it can be called c++11. Which version is considered real c++11-standard? I compiled the code example above using g++ 4.9.2. What standard variant does the compiler use, how can I know? Because versions #3337 or #3367 differ much.

For example, in #3367 the definition of value-initialization was changed dramatically:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> —  if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with either no default constructor (12.1) or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;

**5.** And the new value-initialization definition is strange, in my opinion, as I can't think up any case when we could create and value-initialize an object with **deleted** default constructor. I mean, for example, if I make *int c* member of C-class private  and, thus, C-class stops being an aggregate the expression

```
C obj1 { };
```

will be value-initialization (not aggregate-initialization as it was before) [#3367, 8.5.4 "List-initialization"] and will definitely fail to compile. 
Could you explain the moment about deleted constructors in the new value-initialization definition?

I understand that there is much text here. If you answered some I would be so so so grateful.

Comment: Your `C` is not trivial, because it doesn't have any non-deleted default constructors. Thus there is no object of type `C` whose lifetime has begun.

Comment: `C *obj2 = (C *) malloc(1);` Whaaaattt. You're shall write C++, not C. Such stuff should only be done in container classes and still not with plain `malloc`

Comment: @Superlokkus: More importantly, it *wrong*, since it's not the `sizeof(C)`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Except on a theoretical possible platform where `sizeof(int)  == 1`, but still it's >9000 like bad style.

Comment: @Superlokkus, well, there are just two versions: with placement new (obj2) and usual new expression (obj3) to view the situation more broadly. Why not.

Comment: @Superlokkus: Bad style is irrelevant. Doing `malloc(sizeof(C))` and constructing `C` from it is guaranteed to be legal C++. Doing `malloc(1)` and constructing `C` from it is *not* guaranteed to be legal C++.

Comment: `malloc != new`! `malloc` does not call the constructor and it's not allowed to `delete`, `malloc`ed memory.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I was just a bit distracted, sorry.

Comment: @NicolBolas I know, I was just playing devil's advocate. This code i.e. style has no practical use, I can think of, yet